# QGIS Graphic Modeler: Does Polygon A contain or interset Polygon B

Tags: qgis, polygon

I need to use the Graphic Modeler to decipher if Polygon A (Site Boundary) contains or intersects another multipart polygon.

If the polygon does intersect I need to to return Yes and if not No within a column in the original polygon.

My initial research suggests using v.select... however im not totally sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Select by location" is one solution to your problem. It gives options for you to choose "touches", "intersects", etc.

[image: select by location]

In your model, you can then use the "Field calculator" tool to add a new field called "intersects" and change the attribute to "yes" for all selected features

[image: field calculator]

Comment: Do you know what the formula should be to change the attribures to Yes for the selected features please?

Comment: it just needs to be "Yes". Make sure you set your field type to "string". I've added another image to my answer to illustrate

Comment: I keep getting the follwoing..... Error executing algorithm Field calculator Evaluation error: Column 'YES' not found. Any idea where im going wrong? :)

Comment: My fault... try 'Yes' (with single quotes NOT double quotes)